# Problems with creating a loop in R

Tags: r

I was successful with generating a loop for almost all commands.

this is my `>data.frame`:

```
  Date          OCC1990 DEGREE EMPSTAT 
1    1990-01     457      1      10  
2    1990-01     223      1      10   
3    1990-01     221      0      10   
4    1990-01     229      0      2   
5    1990-02     223      1      10   
6    1990-02     224      0      10    
7    1990-02     225      0      10
```

I successfully created a loop that counts the number of people having a degree and being employed for a certain occupation. So i's in the loop depend on the occupation. The variable `COLLEMP`` refers just to people who are working (regardless the occupation) and who graduated.

```
for (i in 223:229) {
  COLLEGE <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  EMPLOYED <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  
  cps_data[[COLLEGE]] <- ifelse(
    ( 
      (cps_data$COLLEMP %in% c(1)) &
        (cps_data$OCC1990 == i)),
    1*cps_data$HWTFINL, 0) 
  
  cps_data[[EMPLOYED]] <- ifelse(
    ( 
      (cps_data$EMPSTAT %in% c(10))&
        (cps_data$OCC1990 == i)),
    1*cps_data$HWTFINL, 0) 
  
  COLLEGESUM <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  EMPLOYEDSUM <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  COLLEGE_SUM <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  EMPLOYED_SUM <- paste(i, sep = "_")
  OCC <- paste(i, sep = "_") 
  
  COLLEGELAB[[COLLEGESUM]] <- cps_data %>%                                        
    group_by(YEAR) %>%                         
    summarise_at(vars(COLLEGE),             
                 list(COLLEGE_SUM = sum)) 
  COLLEGELAB[[EMPLOYEDSUM]] <- cps_data %>%                                        
    group_by(YEAR) %>%                         
    summarise_at(vars(EMPLOYED),             
                 list(EMPLOYED_SUM = sum)) 
  
  COLLEGELAB[[OCC]] <- cps_data %>%                                        
    group_by(YEAR) %>%                         
    summarise_at(vars(COLLEGE, EMPLOYED),             
                 list(COLLEGE_SUM = sum, EMPLOYED_SUM = sum))
```

Until there, the looping was successful and I stored my results in the data.frame `COLLEGELAB`, which looks like that now:

```
  223.YEAR      223.COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM 223.COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM       224.YEAR      224.COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM 224.COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM   college_rate
1    1990     873221                       1004000   1                   1990              773221                       2024000           desired value 
2    1991     834501                       1030000  2                    1991              734501                       2030000           desired value 
3    1992     834543                       1200000  3                    1992              734543                       2200000          desired value 
4    1993     843500                       1000050  4                    1993              743500                       2000050          desired value 
5    1994     834510                       1040000  5                    1994              734510                       2040000          desired value 
6    1995     834340                       1005000  6                    1995              734340                       2005000          desired value
```

What try to do now, is to divide for example `223.COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM`  by `223.COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM`. This seems to be quite complicated because the two variables contain the different"i's" already, which I used all the time to loop the different occupations.

```
college_rate <- paste(i, sep = "_")
COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM <- paste(i, sep = ".", "COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM")
COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM <- paste(i, sep = ".", "COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM")
#PROBLEM
COLLEGELAB <- transform(COLLEGELAB, college_rate =  
                          COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM / COLLEGE_EMPLOYED_SUM)
```

My last idea, by using the `paste` argument again, did not work due to `non-numeric argument for binary operator`.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to paste the index 'i' in the column name and have multiple copies of the same column ex: 223.COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM, 224.COLLEGE_COLLEGE_SUM.

Simply make a new column called "Index" (or "Loop", or simply "i"), which will keep track of which rows relate to the 'ith' loop and keep only ONE column of each type.

Then to divide any two columns relating to the 'ith' loop, simply pull out the rows relating to the 'ith' loop and divide the values from the columns of interest.

Id like to show you how to do this on your code, but you don't have a reproducible example to go from.

I suggest reviewing [ways for manipulating data.frames](https://paldhous.github.io/ucb/2016/dataviz/week7.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  What is missing to make this example reproducible?

Comment: A reproducible example would allow me to take your code and run it on my computer exactly. Obviously I cannot do that, for instance I dont have cps_data. I cannot just copy your code and run it.